# $_File not sending when sending in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

There are a lot of question about this subject already in stackexchange. I have try all of them but I just can't get it upload a file.

HTML

```
<form id="getjs">
        <input type="file" name="icon_next" id="icon_next">
</form>
<button type="submit" id="submit2" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit2', function(e) {
var icon_next = $('#icon_next')[0].files[0];
//have try FormData('#getjs')
//have try $('#icon_next').serialize();

console.log(icon_prev);// this give File { name: "filter_function - Copy.png", lastModified: 1557632103057, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 91746, type: "image/png" }

var c = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'custom_setting/loadicon',
    data: {'file': icon_next}, 
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) { 
        //this always success
         }

    });
});
```

Function custom_setting/loadicon

```
if (isset($_GET['file'])) {
            $k = 1;
            // Code for upload file
        } else {
            $k = 0;
        }
```

My problem it is always get $k=0; no file had been transmitted. Where have I go wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit2', function(e) {
    let files = new FormData(), // you can consider this as 'data bag'
        url = 'custom_setting/loadicon';

    files.append('fileName', $('#icon_next')[0].files[0]); // append selected file to the bag named 'file'

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: files,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

custom_setting/loadicon

```
if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)) {
    $file = $_FILES['fileName'];
   print_r($file);
    $name = $file['name'];
    $path = $file['tmp_name'];


    // process your file

}
```

Comment: check now my answer and console.log in ajax response so you can know the output fo your php

Comment: It gives me blank. it have to have `$name` like in your code but just blank

Comment: It means you getting response from your php right now check my answer

Answer (score 0):

try with FormData for send all the form

Exmple:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit2', function(e) {
//var icon_next = $('#icon_next')[0].files[0];
var formdata=new FormData(document.getElementById('getjs'));
//have try $('#icon_next').serialize();

console.log(icon_prev);// this give File { name: "filter_function - Copy.png", lastModified: 1557632103057, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 91746, type: "image/png" }

var c = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'custom_setting/loadicon',
    data: formdata, 
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(response) { 
        //this always success
         }

    });
});
```

and in php

```
 if(isset($_FILES['icon_next'])){
       $_FILES['icon_next']['name'];
       $k = 1;
        // Code for upload file
  } else {
            $k = 0;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your form tag with enctype attribute like below

```
<form id="getjs" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="icon_next" id="icon_next">
</form>
```

Function custom_setting/loadicon

```
if (isset($_FILES['icon_next'])) {
    $k = 1;
    // Code for upload file
} else {
    $k = 0;
}
```